# "sudo apt install <anything>" - The list of sources could not be read

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, sublime-text

I have a problem. I want to install Sublime Text, but it always gave me the following error:

```
Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.lits.d/sublime-text.list (Component)
The list of sources could not be read
```

So I tried another installation method via snap. But now, trying to install snapd, the same error occurs

```
Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.lits.d/sublime-text.list (Component)
The list of sources could not be read
```

The first entry of that list reads:

```
#eb cdrom:[Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20180725)]/bionic main restricted
```

I can't find out what to do.

Comment: please edit/paste the full output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.lits.d/sublime-text.list`

Comment: Folder `sources.lits.d` looks suspicious since folder consist of misspelled "list". What is the output of `ls sources.lits.d`?

Comment: /etc/apt/sources.list.d --> "ld" says "no input files"... but I deleted the file before

Comment: @LJag Please look again at the command I specified. It's `ls /etc/apt/sources.lits.d`

Comment: I installed it now by means of Ubuntu Software. source.lits was only a type, excuse me and thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete this file: `/etc/apt/sources.lits.d/sublime-text.list` and install `sublime-text` snap:

```
sudo snap install sublime-text
```

Edit: To install `sublime-text` as snap package, you need to [pass the `--classic` option](https://docs.snapcraft.io/snap-confinement/6233):

```
sudo snap install sublime-text --classic
```

Comment: If I do that, the following error shows up:

"This revision of snap "sublime-text" was published using classinc confinement and thus may perform arbitrary system changes outside of the security sandbox that snaps are usually confined to, which may put your system at tisk." Can I continue or should I install it another way?

Comment: Yes, some snap packages need the `--classic` option. In your case:
`sudo snap install sublime-text --classic`.
It shouldn't be a problem as long as the source is trustworthy, but if you want to read more about this option, see: https://docs.snapcraft.io/snap-confinement/6233